# Metodo genérico para llenar una JTable mediante HashMap

Tags: java

Resulta que tengo un metodo que crea un TableModel a traves de un HashMap, el cual es el siguiente

```
public TableModel modelotebla(HashMap<?,?> map){

DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModelo(columName().toArray, 0);
map.keySet().forEach((sala)-> modelo.addRow(new Object[]{sala, map.get(sala).getNOMBRE_SALA(), map.get(sala).getNOMBRE_PELI()}));
ArraynomColum.clear();
return modelo;

}
```

Como veis estoy utilizando las interrrogaciones en el hashMap pasado por parametro, asi no tendria que declarar el tipo de valores que contiene, el problema es que si uso este comodin (?) me es imposible acceder a los atributos de la clase sala, que esta dentro del hashmap, puesto que java no la indetifica como tal, lo quiero evitar es tener que hacer metodos iguales pero solo cambiando la clase que contiene el hashmap en concreto, nose si me he esplicado bien pero cualquier cosa me podeis preguntar, gracias de antemano

Comment: No vas a poder crear un método tan genérico si necesitas saber el tipo de los valores guardados en el mapa. Una solución parcial sería que esos valores cumpliesen un interfaz común.

Comment: En el método que proporcionas, cada vez que iteras el mapa, a la vez estás haciendo dos búsquedas en le mapa. Ese método es demasiado ineficiente como para querer dejarlo como alguna utilería. ¿porque no mejor conviertes el mapa en una lista y pasas la lista como parámetro?